# Gmail forwarding filters

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

I have a situation where I want all emails with a specific word in the subject field sent to one email address. All other emails I want sent to a different email address.

Then have them set as read and delete. Any one know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

follow the screen shots below.

Search subject:(*word*), the reason i put * is so that it matches with wildcard so no matter where the word appears in the subject it will pass through the filter. Then click on the show search options.

[image]

click on create filter with this search.

[image]

Select what options you want and what email to forward it to.

[image]

And then finally do another search and but putting a - in-front of your word and this means that you do not want that word there.

[image]